# What parameter will help the balls follow the container?

Tags: physics

I am trying to finish a scene and the rigid bodies part is really taking me more than expected.

[image]

The balls show follow the container while it moves.

These are my settings (I also attached the rigid body world settings).
The "Door" mesh opens at one moment and let the balls out.

Can you help me to find out why the balls are not staying in the container ?
I tried with the animated check box on and off...and even increasing substantially the solver iterations and substeps did not help to avoid the issue.

Thank you

[image: Balls]
[image: Contanier]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Thank you Chris! Can I send the file via we transfer?

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.com - and follow instructions

Comment: Yes I tried before and did not work. If it does not work again would you be able to receive wetransfer?

Comment: @Chris As I said "There was an internal error attempting to complete your request"

Comment: I tried several times...the error keeps pop in up